# Alternative to if else statement when using doubles

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Based on the salaries, I need to assign a specific tax rate on my employee objects. The salary is defined by yearlySalary, which is a double, so I couldn't use a switch statement. I instead used if/else:

```
public int getSalaryRank() {
    if(yearlySalary <= 60000.00) {
        salaryRank = 1;
    } else if(yearlySalary > 60000.00 && yearlySalary <= 80000.00) {
        salaryRank = 2;
    } else if(yearlySalary > 80000.00 && yearlySalary <= 100000.00) {
        salaryRank = 3;
    } else if(yearlySalary > 100000.00 && yearlySalary <= 125000.00) {
        salaryRank = 4;
    } else {
        salaryRank = 5;
    } return salaryRank; }
```

I will assign tax rates later on based on the rank. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: The `>` conditions are all redundant - the `else` on each line guarantees what you're checking with `>`.  And don't use `double` for money, please!

Comment: Apart from what @LuiggiMendoza says, given how your code is written, you could just `return` after each `if` statement. If you want some more constructed class for that, have a look at Guava's `Range` class.

Comment: That said, your question  seems to imply that a switch is better than if/else blocks. It's not. switch is usually a sign of poor design, and is a dangerous construct to use (fall-through, etc.)

Comment: Ok thank you, and I will just have to learn BigDecimal

Comment: `return 1 + new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(60000.00, 80000.00, 100000.00, 125000.00)).headSet(yearlySalary, true).size();`

Comment: @DavidWallace I will comment that into the method for me to find out more about it later, since I don't want use right now, as I've never used a treeset before, but thank you

Comment: It's a bit tongue-in-cheek, and I don't think I'd use this solution seriously.  But it (and also @AlexWien's solution) has an advantage over the other solutions here, in that you can get the list of values from a properties file, or a database, or something; rather than hard-coding the fact that there are 4 different threshold values, which may well change.  My best advice is to do two things.  Switch to using `BigDecimal`, then adopt @AlexWien's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it like this:

```
public int getSalaryRank() {
    int salaryRank;

    if(yearlySalary <= 60000.00) {
        return  1;
    } 

    if(yearlySalary <= 80000.00) {
        return 2;
    } 

    if(yearlySalary <= 100000.00) {
        return 3;
    } 

    if(yearlySalary <= 125000.00) {
       return 4;
    } 

    return 5

}
```

All the checks on the left side are unnecessary, because the statements are executed in order. Furthermore, you can remove the else statements and directly return the `salaryrank` . Also when you are dealing with money NEVER EVER use floating point numbers. Use `BigDecimal` instead

Edit: Taking into account @AlexWien's comment about the multiple exit points this might be a better solution:

```
public int getSalaryRank() {
        if(yearlySalary <= 60000.00) {
            salaryRank = 1;
        } else  if(yearlySalary <= 80000.00) {
            salaryRank = 2;
        } else if(yearlySalary <= 100000.00) {
            salaryRank = 3;
        } else if(yearlySalary <= 125000.00) {
           salaryRank = 4;
        } else {
           salaryRank = 5;
        }  

        return salaryRank;

    }
```

Comment: the multiple returns are copied from user Tony, but are bad style  because now having 5 return statements. Try enabling checkstyle. (Bad to debug )

Comment: Multiple exit points might be bad, but for a simple method like this ?

Comment: Yes because you cannot set a break point before returning. But that is opinion dependent. So I did not downvote

Comment: @AlexWien Ever since I saw your comment on multiple returns in a method, I stopped doing them. But I'm wondering, why is it a bad programming practice? When I googled it, I got this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/118717

Comment: @Abdul, Its bad for two reasons: First its hard to set a breakpoint, 2, using the return will not make the code simpler in this case, and last and least, the automatically calculated complexity (Using  SW-Metrics) will be extremly high (2 powered by (number of else clauses)).

Answer (score 4):

Consider using a `while` loop through an List or array of (salary) limits.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
public int getSalaryRank() 
{
    if(yearlySalary <= 60000.00) return 1;
    if(yearlySalary <= 80000.00) return 2;
    if(yearlySalary <= 100000.00) return 3;
    if(yearlySalary <= 125000.00) return 4;
    return 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program will not get to the `else` statement if any of the previous `if`'s were true. So, you could use that to your advantage and leave out the following: `yearlySalary > 60000.00 &&`

```
if(yearlySalary <= 60000.00) {
    salaryRank = 1;
} else if(yearlySalary <= 80000.00) {
    salaryRank = 2;
}
```

Also, doubles aren't particularly precise. They're floating point numbers, which means that you can't accurately hold the value of for instance `0.1`. Look it up. BigDecimal is a better type to use with currency.